# Trying to load second result set from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, multiple-resultsets

I have a customer setup that uses stored procedures to return data from its SQL Server database.

Those stored procedures are all built the same way - they take a bunch of input parameters, and they return:

- the first is just a single row, single column with the result code (type `INT`) - 0 for success, some other values otherwise; if the value is 0, then there's a second result set that contains the actual data
- the second result set can be anything - any number of columns and rows

I'm trying to create a "generic" way to interface with this system, and my attempt is this:

- create a class that takes stored procedure name and input parameters
- a return type that contains both an `ErrorCode INT` property as well as a `DataTable results` property

However, I'm having trouble getting this to work with ADO.NET and SQL Server 2008 R2.

My code boils down to this:

```cs
public MyResultType CallService(string procedureName, MyParameters parameters)
{
     MyResultType result = new MyResultType { ErrorCode = 0 };

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, conn))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         SetupParameters(cmd, parameters);

         // open connection, execute the stored procedure
         conn.Open();

         using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             // get the first result set - the status code, one row, one column of type INT
             while (rdr.Read())
             {
                 result.ErrorCode = rdr.GetInt32(0);
             }

             // if we got a "0" (success) -> go to the next result set and load it into the table
             if(result.ErrorCode == 0 && rdr.NextResult())
             {
                 result.ResultTable = new DataTable();
                 result.ResultTable.Load(rdr);

                 int colCount = result.ResultTable.Columns.Count;
                 int rowCount = result.ResultTable.Rows.Count;
              }

              rdr.Close();
         }

         conn.Close();
   }

   return result;
}
```

My issue is: the call to the stored procedure works just fine, the error code = 0 is picked up just fine, the data table is created and the number of columns is the expected value - but there are **NO ROWS** loaded...

I've been trying everything I can think of to get those rows into the DataTable - no luck. And of course - if I execute this very same stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, everything works just fine, I get my ErrorCode=0 and my result set of 18 columns and 5 rows - no problem....

What am I missing? Can anyone spot the problem in my code? Why aren't the rows of the second result set loaded (but the columns are being detected, it seems)?

Comment: The fact that the column count is the expected value and the "result" table is created appropriately (except without rows) suggests that there is some difference in how the stored procedure is being called from the "console" (SQL Server Management Studio) and from your ADO.Net code.  In particular what arguments does the stored procedure take?  You reference without exposing them as "parameters" in the snippet of code above.

Comment: Should be able to check this by running a profiler trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code as published works fine - there was a difference between how I call it from C# and in SQL Server Management Studio : NULL handling.

I had some input parameters set to `int` and thus provided a `0` value to the stored procedure, while it really expected to get a `NULL` if the value isn't defined......

Stupid rookie mistake..... SORRY GUYS! And thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

The [DataTable.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) implicitly calls the NextResult method, so combining that with your explicit call, it is advancing to a resultset that isn't there.  You should remove your own call to NextResult if you want to use DataTable.Load *or* loop through and fill a datatable yourself.

Comment: `DataTable.Load` calls `NextResult` **after** it's loaded its result set.... if I don't put `.NextResult()` there, then I'm loading the first result set (just one row, one column) again. I tested that already